# Can't connect IBAction to view

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS and I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews).

Here is a screenshot of me trying to connect an IBAction to my view.

I want to execute the method `releaseKeyboard` whenever I touch the view (ie. close the keyboard).

I'm not using storyboard.

[image: screenshot]

My files:

- challAppDelegate.h
- challAppDelegate.m
- challViewController.h
- challViewController.m
- challViewController.xib

challAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface challAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

challAppDelegate.m

```
#import "challAppDelegate.h"
#import "challViewController.h"

@implementation challAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *rootController =
    [[challViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"challViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
...
...
```

challViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface challViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *signInEmailAddress;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *signInPassword;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *signInSignInButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *signInRegisterButton;

-(void) releaseKeyboardAction;

-(IBAction) signInAction:(int)sender;

-(IBAction) registerAction:(int)sender;

-(IBAction) releaseKeyboard:(id)sender;

@end
```

challViewController.m

```
#import "challViewController.h"

@interface challViewController ()

@end

@implementation challViewController

@synthesize signInEmailAddress; // cria os getters e setters
@synthesize signInPassword; // cria os getters e setters

@synthesize signInSignInButton; // cria os getters e setters
@synthesize signInRegisterButton; // cria os getters e setters

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"Sign In";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)releaseKeyboardAction
{
    [signInEmailAddress resignFirstResponder];
    [signInPassword resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)releaseKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    [self releaseKeyboardAction];
}

- (IBAction)registerAction:(int)sender
{
    //
}

- (IBAction)signInAction:(int)sender
{
    //
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can't connect a `IBAction` as a `IBOutlet` for your view. What do you want to do with the view and the `releaseKeyboard:` method?

Comment: To release the keyboard when you press anywhere in the view (since the keyboard doesn't have an exit button). I did connect IBActions to textFields and buttons.

Comment: There is a "Done" button - when you press this on the keyboard do you want the keyboard to disappear?

Comment: I want that when I touch anywhere on the screen (besides the keyboard) makes the keyboard disappear.

Comment: "To release the keyboard when you press anywhere in the view (since the keyboard doesn't have an exit button). I did connect IBActions to textFields and buttons."

You're connecting their `IBAction`s such as touch events etc.

Comment: This isn't built in annoyingly. You'd have to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Using the storyboard, I simply created this method and connect to the view with the event Touch Up Inside

Comment: I think the tutorial probably asked you to add a button the size of the view, and behind all the other elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `self.view`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"Sign In";

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(releaseKeyboardAction)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

The target of the gesture recogniser points to your `releaseKeyboardAction` method.

Comment: This is correct, but you can also add the gesture recognizer in the nib editor.  No typing required!  Just drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the view, then select the gesture recognizer, go to the connections inspector, and drag from Received Actions to the view controller and make the IBAction connection.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano I'd still make the "Done" button on the keyboard dismiss the keyboard too though! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the view's class from `UIView` to `UIControl` in the identity inspector and then you can connect `IBActions`.